# keras CNN model.predict_classes return array of 3 element

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, prediction

I trained a model on Keras in CNN, it supposes to get the input of image with shape `(-1,32,32,1)` 
after training, I tested the model by inputting new images to the model and get the prediction using model.predict_class and check if the prediction matches the desired label, but the model returns an array of 3 elements for example `([3 12 22])` why it doesn't return one class '

this is the preprocessing code of the image before the prediction

```
        read_img = cv2.imread('test-images/' + file + '/' + img)
        read_img = read_img.reshape( -1,32, 32, 1)
        read_img = read_img.astype('float32')/255
        maxind = model.predict_classes(read_img)
```

and this is the output of the prediction

```
[22 12  4]
```

the code used to build the model :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2,padding='same',activation='relu',input_shape=(32,32,1)))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(24, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

model inputs, outputs and image shape

```
model.inputs = [tf.Tensor 'conv2d_1_input:0' shape=(?, 32, 32, 1) dtype=float32]

model.outputs = [tf.Tensor 'dense_2/Softmax:0' shape=(?, 24) dtype=float32]

read_img.shape = (3, 32, 32, 1)
```

Comment: the output depends on the last layer of your keras model. Can you include the code you used to built the model

Comment: sure I will edit the question above

Comment: Please show your network architecture

Comment: @ I edited the question the architecture is above

Comment: What is shape of ```read_img```?

Comment: @Sharan_Sundar it will classify for 24 labels like the mnist but higher

Comment: ```read_img.shape``` is (3, 32, 32, 1). Hence you are passing 3 images and you are getting 3 labels as output.

Comment: @VivekMehta so basically I need to convert the image to grayscale to eliminate the 3 and get one image, what if I want to input the RGB with to transformation to gray is it possible

Comment: @Hassan_mohammad No, your network's input_shape is (32,32,1) which is single channel, you need to train again with RGB images for to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: you've got vector of 3 classes because you put into your network 3 images. Please see the shape of your input tensor/

```py
read_img.shape = (3, 32, 32, 1)
```

The first dimension - 3 - it's batch size which means that your network makes prediction for examples - and that's the reason why you your prediction has 3 classes. Please check the dimension of your input image to be sure for how many photos you make prediction.
If you'd like to make prediction for one photo your input have to has the shape `(1,32,32,1)`.

Comment: that's right it worked when I transformed it from RGB to grayscale